# Clustering Strings Based on Similar Word Sequences

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, clustering, text-mining

In my dataset I have a feature having below data :

### Input

| Feature |
| --- |
| Brain Dementia Routine(Comfortone) |
| Morning Check |
| Dementia Brain-Routine(Comfortone) |
| Brain MRA Routine (Comfortone) |
| Brain-Dementia/Routine(MRCP) |
| MRCP BH WITH DYNAMIC**** |
| LIVER/MRCP W/O, W/ |
| MRCP Routine 30slice |
| MRCP-Routine/Dr.Robert |

How do I   cluster values that have similar words in it .

### Output

| Feature | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| Brain Dementia Routine(Comfortone) | A |
| Morning Check | C |
| Dementia Brain-Routine(Comfortone) | A |
| Brain MRA Routine (Comfortone) | A |
| Brain-Dementia/Routine(Comfortone) | A |
| MRCP BH WITH DYNAMIC**** | B |
| LIVER/MRCP W/O, W/ | B |
| MRCP Routine 30slice | B |
| Dr.Robert/MRCP Routine/ | B |

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a sentence embedding model to associate a vector to each of your inputs, and use a clustering algorithm like KMeans, or build a similarity matrix between your strings using a string distance metric, and use a similarity-based algorithm like Spectral Clustering or Agglomerative Clustering.

The first one using KMeans might not work the best because the sentence embedding model will have been trained on data that doesn't specifically look like what you have, but it will be able to process new data.

For the second one, because you can use any string distance you want, you can design one that works really well with your data. But because it uses similarity based clustering, you wont be able to process new data as easily.